# LOGFONT text rotation causes the text to change size

Tags: c++, gdi, win32gui

I tried rotating the text by 270 degrees

```
    HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

    LOGFONT lf;

    lf.lfHeight = 40;
    lf.lfWidth = 0;
    lf.lfEscapement = 2700;
    lf.lfOrientation = 2700;
    lf.lfWeight = FW_SEMIBOLD;
    lf.lfItalic = 0;
    lf.lfUnderline = 0;
    lf.lfStrikeOut = 0;
    lf.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
    lf.lfOutPrecision = 0;
    lf.lfClipPrecision = 0;
    lf.lfQuality = 0;
    lf.lfPitchAndFamily = 0;
    strcpy(lf.lfFaceName, "Arial");
    hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

    SelectObject(hdc, hFont);

    TextOut(hdc, 120, 79, "hello", SIGNED_STRLEN("hello"));
```

However the size of the font gets bigger when the `lfEscapement` and `lfOrientation` parameters are set to 2700 for a 270 degrees as opposed to 0 for no rotation.

How do I keep the text size the same when I rotate it?

Comment: `LOGFONT lf;` -- This struct is uninitialized.  It will contain undefined values at where you do not set them.  Many issues that pertain to using these structs are due to using them uninitialized, filling in only some of the members, and giving that to the Windows API to process.  Instead, try this: `LOGFONT lf {};`

Comment: I have given every element of the struct a value here although you are right that is a better way of initialising to avoid leaving things as undefined/unknown defaults

Comment: *I have given every element of the struct a value here* -- You are not in control of the struct.  It is a Windows struct, and who knows what the SDK may do to it now or in the future.  For laughs and giggles, initialize the struct and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Okay so I initialised it within the brackets instead and still same issue. Text becomes bigger when I rotate it.

Comment: GDI font rotation is all kinds of funky. On top of that, if you create a `HFONT` with any given `lfHeight` (regardless of whether you're specifying cell height or character height), you are not guaranteed to get a `HFONT` with that actual height in its `TEXTMETRICW`. As part of the `HFONT` instantiation, GDI may decide that the height you want is "inconvenient", and may slightly change it. This kind of problem is what `lfQuality` was originally for, but that flag is practically obsolete now. In some cases if you are very lucky, specifying `lfHeight = -35` instead of `+40` *might* help a bit.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, using `GM_ADVANCED` with `SetWorldTransform` has the exact same issue, just tried that :/